# Seed based randomization perl

Tags: perl, random, seed

I have an array defined say `@Array(1..31)`. Now I have a code where I randomly select a number for a certain number of times and store the results in another array. Example below :

```
$a1 = $Array[rand(@Array)];
push (@a2, $a1);
```

Now when I execute this script multiple times, I see that the new array contains very different patter everytime. But I do not want that, I want to generate a similar pattern everytime- where seed comes into picture.

*Can someone please help me in how to incorporate seed to randomly select elements from array which can be predictable*.?

Comment: Use [`srand`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/srand.html).

Comment: I tried srand, but it is giving an error : Deep recursion routine

Comment: [Edit] your question to show the code you used and the error you got.

Comment: I removed the calling of recursion subroutine, but now it is only selecting only 1 number from the array constantly whenever I am calling the subroutine to create a random number.

Comment: sub random 
{
   my  @a1 = @_;
   my $size = @a1;
    my $random_select = $a1[srand(@a1)];
    print " The random number selected is $random_select \n";
    return $random_select;
}

Comment: If you use the same seed, `rand` will generate the same results every time you run your script. Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: No, actually this subroutine is called multiple times in the script by another routine till the array from which random number is generated has exhausted. So basically , if I have array containing 1..31 , then this subroutine if executed I want all 31 numbers to be printed randomly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79727/discussion-between-user3304726-and-thissuitisblacknot).

Comment: No, actually this subroutine is called multiple times in the script by another routine till the array from which random number is generated has exhausted. So basically , if I have array containing 1..31 , then this subroutine if executed I want all 31 numbers to be printed randomly. SO the sample output for the firstime the script .pl executes is
20, 10, 5, ...... so on
but now If I execute the script the second time , I want 20, 10 ,5....so on again
can you please help me in this

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the code that you think isn't working. Also, `rand` can return the same value multiple times; you want [`List::Util::shuffle`](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html#%40values-%3d-shuffle-%40values).

Answer (score 1):

You do not replace `rand` with `srand`: you use `srand` to initialize the seed for `rand`: so call `srand(0)` once and then use `rand` as you had been.

From your comment, you can use:

```
srand(0);
sub random {
    my $random_select = $_[rand(@_)];
    print " The random number selected is $random_select\n";
    return $random_select;
}
```

or back to your original code just add the first line to it:

```
BEGIN { srand(0) }
$a1 = $Array[rand(@Array)];
push (@a2, $a1);
```